# Independence of Lebesgue Random Variables

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-measure, independence

Let $X,Y,Z, F$ be random variables on the probability space $([0,1],B[0,1],Leb)$.

$X(ω)=1$  if $ω$ $∈$ [$\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{3}{4}$], and $X(ω)=0$ if $ω$ $∈$ [$0$,$\frac{1}{4}$)$\cup$($\frac{3}{4}$,$1$].

$Y(ω)=1$ if $ω$ $∈$ [$0$,$\frac{1}{2}$) and $Y(ω)=0$ if $ω$ $∈$ [$\frac{1}{2}$,$1$].

$Z(ω)=0$ if $ω$ $∈$ $[0$,$\frac{1}{2})$ and $Z(ω)=1$ if $ω$ $∈$ [$\frac{1}{2}$,$1]$.

$F(ω)=ω$

How do I check if the random variables are independent?

I know that independent variables hold the following property: $P(A \cap B)$ = $P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Set up events.  Simple example $A=(Y\lt 1/2)$ and $B=(Z\gt 1/2)$ $P(A\cap B)=0$ while $P(A)P(B)=1/4$.  Therefore $Y$ and $Z$ not independent.

Comment: @herbsteinberg why is the intersection 0?

Comment: A requires $\omega \lt 1/2$ while B requires $\omega ge 1/2$.  I mistyped my thought.  I meant $A=(Y=1)$ and $B=(Z=1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as $Y=-Z$ a.e. it is easy to see that these are not independent. Also $X,Y,Z$ are functionally dependent on $F$, so it is clear that these are dependent.

Then we need to check for if some event for one variable gives us information for the other variable.

E.g.: If $X=1$ the distributions of $Y,Z$ do not change, both are $0$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. Similarly if $X=0$. Thus $X,Y$ and $X,Z$ are independent.

But if $X=1$ the distribution of $F$ changes, as it then takes values between $1/4$ and $3/4$ instead of $0,1$ (although we already know that these are dependent).

Comment: The idea is: If $X$ is not constant and $Y=f(X)$ a.e. is not constant. Then we can find a non trivial event $E$ so that $F=\{Y\in E\}$ has positive, but not full mass. But then under $Y\in E$ we have that $X\in F$ does not have full mass. So they are not independent.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. So to sum up, only X and Y, and X and Z are independent pairs right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Note that we only need to consider the Events $X=0$ and $X=1$, as $X$ does not take any other values.